# How to hide the message when a user clicks somewhere else in the screen

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, message

I am trying to make messages disappear after 40 seconds of inaction or when the user clicks somewhere else in the screen but I only managed to do the 40 seconds.

I wrote this php and it can display different types of messages

```
 <?php
     if(isset($_SESSION['message'])): ?>
        <div id="myMsg" class ="alert alert-<?=$_SESSION['type']?>">
            <?php
                echo $_SESSION['message'];
                unset($_SESSION['message']);
           ?>
       </div>
    <?php endif ?>
```

This is the script that i wrote and this is were i have to add the other functionality that i want

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 
function timedMsg()
{
var t=setTimeout("document.getElementById('myMsg').style.display='none';",40000);
}
 
</script>
```

Thanks a lot for your time

Answer (score 0):

Better use a callback *function* for `setTimeout`. For hiding on click use an event handler (preferably with [event delegation](https://javascript.info/event-delegation)) Like this:

```js
const hideMsg = () => document.querySelector("#msg").classList.add("hide")
document.addEventListener("click", hideMsg);
const to = setTimeout(hideMsg, 40000);
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

#msg {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div id="msg">
  Some Message (disappears after 40 seconds), 
  or click anywhere to hide
</div>
```

Comment: The string also works - not recommended but it works. OP needs it to ALSO disappear when clicking elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

You can add a blur event Listener on the message 
An example:

```
const message = document.querySelector('#myMsg')
message.addEventListener("blur", () => {
  message.style.display='none'
});
```

Comment: That requires the message to have focus